# Can MediaRouter be used to detect mirroring?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediarouter

I am using [MediaRouter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/mediarouter/media/MediaRouter) from [androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/mediarouter)

Can someone confirm, suggest a better solution, or correct me if this code can properly detect mirroring:

```kotlin
fun Activity.isExternalDisplayConnected(): Boolean {
    return MediaRouter.getInstance(this).routes.any { route ->
        !route.isDefault && route.playbackType == MediaRouter.RouteInfo.PLAYBACK_TYPE_REMOTE
    }
}
```

So basically I am checking if there is any Route that is not default and `playbackType` is `PLAYBACK_TYPE_REMOTE`.

It works on my two test devices but I am curious if this will generally work every time. And if this function can return true on some devices that don't have mirroring turned on.

Comment: Having a connected external display does not imply mirroring. The foreground app might be showing something using `Presentation` or similar techniques. Or, the device might be in some new UI mode, such as Samsung DeX.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, do You know what is the best way to decide if a device is mirrored? And a reversed question, does mirroring imply that an external device is connected to the device? (so when a device is mirrored this function will always return true?)

Comment: "You know what is the best way to decide if a device is mirrored?" -- I do not know of any way of doing it. "does mirroring imply that an external device is connected to the device?" -- no. At minimum, there is a developer option in Settings to simulate an external display, and by default, it mirrors.